# Is there an Android API feature to tell when the user is looking at the device?

Tags: android, android-intent, motorola

The Moto X comes with a feature that keeps the screen on when the user is looking at it. Is there an API that allows a third-party app to tell if the user is looking at the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in standard Android. Device manufacturers may offer ones specific for their devices.

Comment: Thanks! Which leads to the more specific question: does Motorola provide such an API for their devices?

Comment: @scottgwald: Not that I am aware of, but I haven't gone looking for it either.

Comment: I have gone looking and I see no evidence of any [Moto-specific packages](http://www.motorola.com/us/Motorola-Developers/motorola-developers.html)... which is a little surprising and disappointing as well if it is the case. It seems a little daunting to go digging [here](https://github.com/MotorolaMobilityLLC/system-core/tree/kitkat-4.4.4-release-victara). Surely there's a better way...

Comment: @scottgwald: On the whole, Motorola gave up on developer support a couple years ago (as they were acquired twice).